# What software can I use to automatically click the OK button in a 'Remote Desktop Session Time Limit' pop-up?

Tags: remote-desktop

We have an **application** installed in a **Remote Desktop Service(RDS)**. But due to **Session Time Limit** enforced, we are being prompted with the **Idle timer expired** pop-up whenever there is inactivity.

[image]

In our **application**, there is a report generation wherein it takes much time longer than the session time limit. **Is there a software we can use to create an application that will be installed in the RDS server to automatically click the OK button whenever it pop-ups?**

Please note that we cannot change the session time limit configuration in RDS which is the very direct solution, but due to some policy, we cannot. So, this is what we think as a workaround.

If you are also thinking, that we can just click the button right away by ourselves to prevent us from disconnecting but since report generation takes too long we sometimes do other tasks or leave our machine open and we could not look over the Idle timer pop-up.

Any recommendation is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A non-free program that I use for similar situations is [MacroExpress](https://www.macroexpress.com/). It permits one to create scripts based on window appearance, program execution, and other types of conditions.

For your specific circumstance, I can envision determining the executable which generates the window, writing a script which waits for that executable to start and activating the mouse click (or press enter) to clear the pop-up. Looping is also a feature of the software.

It's likely there are other similar programs, perhaps free, that will do the same thing, but I'm familiar only with MacroExpress.

Comment: Thanks @fred_dot_u! I'll take this as one of my options to try.